# possible to get an early exit on a distinct sqlite query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

I need to query the number of distinct items in a particular SQLite table and column. However, there are millions of rows, and I only care if there are more than 20 distinct items. Is there any way to put an early exit in the distinct/group by counter?

Comment: For us to help you we need some table structure?

Comment: I don't understand your question: what exactly are you querying for? The number of distinct records if there are less than 20, otherwise 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT must work

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1,column2
FROM table
WHERE column3='some value'
LIMIT 20
```

based on this, http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT field FROM huge_table LIMIT 20;
```

Check out the reference on the SQLite's [`SELECT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) command.

Comment: It appears your answer was the same as the other, but I marked the other as the answer because it came in first.